# Barplot for a range of numbers appearing in column - python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, python-2.7, seaborn

I have a column where values are either NOT_TESTED, NOT_COMPLETED, TOO_LOW, or a value between 150 and 190, seperated by 5, so 150, 155, 160etc).

```
num_range = range(150,190, 5)
OUTCOMES = ['NOT_TESTED', 'NOT_COMPLETED', 'TOO_LOW', num_range]
df["outcomes_col"] = df["TP1"].astype ("category")
df["outcomes_col"].cat.set_categories(OUTCOMES , inplace = True )
sns.countplot(x= "outcomes_col", data=df, palette='Magma')
plt.xticks(rotation = 90)
plt.ylabel('Amount')
plt.xlabel('Outcomes')
plt.title("Outcomes per testing")
plt.show()
```

This is the code I created, it works fine except when I need to get the numerical values between 150&190. I have tried different ways like `xrange()` or `tuple(range(150,190, 5)` for num_range but none of these work.
I need each value (150, 155 etc) to have its own stick in the barplot that represents how many time it appears in that column "TP1"

Any guidance?

Using python2.7

Answer (score 0):

You can do as below:

```
num_range = range(150,190, 5)
OUTCOMES = ['NOT_TESTED', 'NOT_COMPLETED', 'TOO_LOW']
OUTCOMES.extend(list(num_range))


Output:
['NOT_TESTED',
 'NOT_COMPLETED',
 'TOO_LOW',
 150,
 155,
 160,
 165,
 170,
 175,
 180,
 185]
```

Maybe then you can categorize and continue with the rest.

Comment: So this is getting me closer to the solution, it outputs the barplot with the correct OUTCOMES and values on the x-axis but does not show any value for the numbers 150-190 (so no stick), as if the values never appear in the column. Do you know why that could be?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
num_range = list(range(150,190, 5)) #as list

OUTCOMES = ['NOT_TESTED', 'NOT_COMPLETED', 'TOO_LOW']
OUTCOMES.extend(num_range) #extend it with the list of numbers

#add numbers to the TP1 column
df = df.append(pd.DataFrame(num_range, 
               columns=['TP1']),
               ignore_index = True)

df["outcomes_col"] = df["TP1"].astype("category")
df["outcomes_col"].cat.set_categories(OUTCOMES , inplace = True )
sns.countplot(x= "outcomes_col", data=df, palette='Magma')
plt.xticks(rotation = 90)
plt.ylabel('Amount')
plt.xlabel('Outcomes')
plt.title("Outcomes per testing")
plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: At first glance, this works very well but as is seen in your output, all the values for the numbers are 1. In my dataset, 165 appears 3 times for example so the stick should go up to 3, why is it that they all have the same value?

Comment: Please provide additional details in your answer. As it's currently written, it's hard to understand your solution.

Comment: The variables between 150-190 should have varying stick height, corresponding to the number of time a value appears in the column TP1. For example, 165 appears 3 times so the stick height of the barplot for that one should be 3. 185 appears 5 times, stick height should be 5. When using the code above, all numbers 150-190 output a stick height of 1. Why is this the case? I hope this clears things up, if not I will attempt to clarify again.